# Compiled gcc4.4.6 on one machine, how to let another machine use it?

Tags: linux, gcc, x86-64, cross-compiling

I built gcc 4.4.6 (to use CUDA) on a fast server, it takes about 10 min. However, on my own desktop, it takes kinda for ever to compile.

So both machines are 64 bit Linux, although 1 is Ubuntu while the other is Arch Linux. Arch Linux has new kernel version.

So on the server, I installed the built gcc-4.4.6 to /opt. And I just copy /opt/gcc-4.4.6 to my PC's /opt/gcc-4.4.6.

em, seems like it doesn't quite work, when I tried 
./x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc ~/Development/c/hello/hello.c

it shows
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory

So what can I do now?

Thanks,
Alfred

Comment: Surely this is just a path problem?

Comment: the amazing thing is where this cc1 is and how to associate a paticular "cc1" to a particular "gcc" executable. I used "find" and cc1 is not in /opt, which I installed the built gcc 4.4.6.

Answer (score 0):

If the systems are similar enough, you could compile GCC on the big machine (don't forget that GCC needs to be configured and built in a directory *outside* of its source tree), then run `make -j3 all` and then `make install DESTDIR=/tmp/gccinst/` and copy that `/tmp/gccinst` directory to your small machine, and finally copy it into the root filesystem (on the small machine).

However, GCC 4.4.6 is quite old today, if you are compiling GCC try to compile **GCC 4.6.2** (or 4.6.1 at least).

And (shameless plug for my work) if you compile a GCC 4.6, please enable plugins on it, then you might try the [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) [meta-] plugin (MELT is a high level domain specific language to ease the development of GCC extensions).